# Next.js caching requests to database used in `getStaticPaths` and `getStaticProps` to improve build time

Tags: next.js

I have several dynamic pages which use exactly same `getStaticPaths` and also invoke exactly same database request in `getStaticProps`. How can I cache results of database requests so they can be reused when building different pages? I have tried to add basic in-memory memoization but it seems like it does not do much. My guess is that pages might be rendered in different workers and they don't share memory.

Comment: what does speak against a traditional cache (redis, memcache, ..)?

Comment: I deploy on Netlify platform and I can't install additional tools there except Node runtime.

Answer (score 1):

If you have heavy computations / requests, you can make a helper that would fetch data from the database and store results in a temporary file. So, you can check whether this file is created and then read it or it's a first request and data needs to be fetched from the database.

Comment: This is what I end up doing, but problem is sometime two requests might run at the same time so there is still double fetch. I guess the only way around is to introduce custom build step and pre-fill files with results from database.